# CloudSearch indexes run but searchable documents is ZERO

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on AWS Cloudsearch with DynamoDB, Multiple domains are running and working fine. But When I try to create a new one, make. every process. which is mentioned in this documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-domain-info.html but searchable documents are zero(0). And If i check the monitoring tab it shows me that request receive successfully but Searchable document is not working. Does anyone know about this?

I tried to setup cloudsearch in my golang project as I have multiple environment so I need to configure a new cloudsearch with DynamoDB, But unfortunately, it isn't running.